# Create window and listen on native messages in nodejs

Tags: node.js, windows, hwnd

Already for a hole year I try time to time again to create a windows window in nodejs to get the native handl and listen to incoming messages.

I used as a workaround an electron window. But creating a full-blown browser just to listen to windows native messages is not a solution. Also, There are too many problems with native addons and electron.

I don't have experiences in writing native addons or event just writing c++/c code.

Does anybody have a solution for this? The problem is, I have an api which requires to send the hwnd of a window to a program and then it sends native messages to the window.

Comment: Probably this? https://github.com/waitingsong/node-win32-api/blob/master/demo/create_window.ts

Answer (score 0):

Use IPCRender to communicate `icpMain.on` to listen and `ipcRenderer.send` to send.

BrowserWindow1 -> BrowserCode -> BrowserWindow2

[image]

Comment: Yeah but I want to get away from electron. Also I am not talking abour communicating between electron main process and main window.